# When some text was click in an TextEdit，then a new tab was opened

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am developing an VSCode Extension. I want to achieve such a function， when some text was click in an TextEdit，then a new tab was opened.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`DocumentLinkProvider`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#_a-namedocumentlinkprovideraspan-classcodeitem-id894documentlinkproviderspan) for this.

[This example extension](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/contentprovider-sample) shows how this can be used. You can activate any command as a document link using the [`command:` uri scheme](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api-commands#_links)